# How do you add Gaussian Noise to a tif image file in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-image, opencv

I am trying to add Gaussian noise to a set of tif files. I have used both scikit-image and cv2.

Scikit-Image: `noise_img = random_noise(np_img, mode='gaussian', seed=None, clip=True)`

CV2:

```
gauss = gauss.reshape(np_img.shape[0], np_img.shape[1], np_img.shape[2]).astype('uint8')
noise_img = cv2.add(np_img, gauss)
```

I used both methods on traditional jpeg and png images and they work. However, they don't seem to work on tif files. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would guess that your TIFF image has a `shape` or `dtype` that is somehow incompatible with the noise functions but as you haven't shared the TIFF file, I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation, https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/experimental/image/decode_tiff, you can decode a .tiff image in Tensorflow with the following function:

```
image = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0, name=None)
```

Later on you can add your desired operations. Please note that on your image you can only use in this case functions from `tf*` not from other libraries such as PIL or OpenCV.